# Odds of selecting all other outcomes besides desired outcome in a series (more BAG O’ MARBLES probability)

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Someone has probably already answered this but I don’t know enough math jargon to search properly.

If I have a bag of ten marbles, nine white and one black, the odds of my pulling the black marble is
1:10

Let’s say I pull wrong, which I likely will, and that white marble that I’ve selected gets removed from the bag. Now, my odds of pulling the black is
1:9

Assume I do this a total of nine times, and I’ve pulled out every white marble until ultimately I have the one black marble left.

How would I find out the odds I would pull all the whites out before the one black?

Are my odds essentially
1/10x9x8x7x6x5x4x3x2x1 ?

1:3,628,800 ?

That can’t possibly be right.

Comment: Each ball is equally likely to be last, so $\frac 1{10}$

Comment: Note:  probability and odds are not the same thing (though they are closely related).  I phrased the answer as a probability.

Comment: But what is the probability of pulling every other marble besides the desired one? Given that each undesired marble pulled is removed?

Comment: Like I said $\frac 1{10}$.  Each ball is equally likely to be drawn last.

Answer (score 1):

If all 10 balls are distinct, then there are $10! = 10 \times 9 \times \ldots \times 1 = 3,628,800$ different orders the balls can come out of the bag, and the probability of drawing them in any specific one of those orders is $\frac{1}{362880}$.

However, if the black ball is fixed to be the last ball drawn, there are $9! = 9 \times \ldots \times 1 = 362,880$ different orders that the 9 white balls can be drawn from the bag. So the probability that the balls come out with the black one last is $\frac{362880}{3628800} = \frac{1}{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

The comment of lulu is conclusive.  The (somewhat inelegant) way of reaching the same result, through direct multiplication of the probability of the respective events is

$$\frac{9}{10} \times \frac{8}{9} \times \cdots \times \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{2}. \tag1 $$

In (1) above, the first fraction represents the probability that the first marble selected is white.

The next fraction represents the probability that the second marble selected is white, **given that the first marble selected was white**.  That is, just before the second drawing, there are $9$ marbles left, $8$ of which are white.

Each subsequent fraction is similar.  For example, the fraction of $~\displaystyle \frac{2}{3}~$ represents the probability of the eighth draw being white, given that all previous draws are white.  That is, just before the eighth draw, there are $3$ marbles left, $2$ of which are white.